# Solr can't find resource stopwords_en.txt

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, stop-words

I'm trying to setup Solr 3.6.0 with Django-haystack Beta 2.0.0.

After running `./manage.py build_solr_schema` and moving schema.xml to the conf directory, upon visiting `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`, I receive an error exactly like the one produced in [this thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solr-error-after-relacing-schema-xml-td3940133.html).

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No cores were created, please check the logs for errors`

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'stopwords_en.txt' in classpath or 'solr/./conf/', cwd=/home/randall/startupsearch_live/apache-solr-3.6.0/example`

At the bottom of the thread, a user mentions that schema.xml must be edited to match stopwords_en.txt to the /example/solr/conf/ directory, which I did both through a symbolic link and by editing all instances of stopwords.txt to /solr/conf/stopwords_en.txt in the generated schema.xml file. However, the same error persists, giving a slightly different output:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource '/solr/conf/stopwords_en.txt' in classpath or 'solr/./conf/', cwd=/home/randall/startupsearch_live/apache-solr-3.6.0/example`

What file must I edit to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can't find `stopwords_en.txt` file in the classpath. You should add `stopwords_en.txt` file into the `solr/conf/` directory. You can find more information about stopwords [here.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Stopwords)

Answer (score 6):

A better way is to find all occurrences of **stopwords_en.txt** in **schema.xml** and replace them with **lang/stopwords_en.txt**

Answer (score 2):

You have to put stopwords_en.txt in the path .
Make a file name stopwords_en.txt and paste beside the schema.xml.
I hope you know what stopword filter is used.....

Answer (score 1):

To combine all three of the above answers, you need the stopwords_en.txt as it begins testing for English language text

From http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Stopwords

> Stopwords affect Solr in three ways: relevance, performance, and
>   resource utilization.
>
> From a relevance perspective, these extremely high-frequency terms
>   tend to throw off the scoring algorithm, and you won't get very good
>   results if you leave them. At the same time, if you remove them, you
>   can return bad results when the stopword is actually important.
>
> From a performance perspective, if you keep stopwords, some queries
>   (especially phrase queries) can be very slow.
>
> From a resource utilization perspective, if you keep stopwords, the
>   index is much larger than if you remove them.
>
> One tradeoff you can make if you have the disk space: You can use
>   CommonGramsFilter/CommonGramsQueryFilter instead of StopFilter. This
>   solves the relevance and performance problems, at the expense of even
>   more resource utilization, because it will form bigrams of stopwords
>   to their adjacent words.

What you need to do is copy the original version located in the /conf/lang folder of your solr directory into just the /conf directory

```
cp PATH/TO/solr/conf/lang/stopwords_en.txt PATH/TO/solr/conf
```

Answer (score 1):

In Solr 5 I got the same error. I had used the Solr zookeeper cli shell to upload my configuration. I had copied the contents of an existing solr config from the server/solr/configsets/basic_configs, but I somehow missed the lang directory.

The conf/lang directory contains stopwords_en.txt.